# ArangoDB Graph shows different result every time

Tags: arangodb

I'm new to ArangoDB and currently trying to display the "Game of Thrones" and "debian_dependency_graph" from the Example Datasets.

In the GoT case I'm able to get the full view by using "Fetch full Graph". Yet there doesn't seem to be a way to add "Traits" in a useful way.

Even stranger is the behavior of the debian_dependency_graph which gives a random, but useful result at first, but changes to nodes only with no added edges after displaying everything.

I'm aware we're starting with a random graph in the beginning, but why isn't there a useful way to switch between the possibilities? Also how comes in the Debian-packages the edges are gone after displaying everything?

From looking through the web I see that in previous versions there seemed to be a way for adding filters and doing changes, in my version (3.4.1, rocksdb)
I can't make much sense of "Configure graph settings". Is there something I'm missing out?
For instance services or showing AQL-Queries as graphs. I'm still trying to figure out what's out.

Screenshot of the Debian dependency graph (Full graph):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "**Configure graph settings**" option which you mentioned above is a right tool for you to use.

- You can force graph to be rendered starting from a specific node if you change **Startnode** (the value should be equal to **_id** property value of a particular object within your graph)
- The problem with the missing edges looks like a limitation of the graph viewer (you are trying to display too many object at the same time and it will be a complete mess if it would render all the edges)
- You can play with **Search Depth** & **Limit** settings to limit the amount of nodes being rendered at the same time which will allow you to see edges

[image: ArangoDB: Configure graph settings]